# Why after deleting mysql-bin.index does my server SQL connect again in MAMP otherwhise it does not?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mamp

When I install MAMP, everything works fine the first time. Apache server connects and SQL also, I can access phpMyAdmin page also. But after turning off the server and turning it on again, MySQL doesn’t connect anymore, and in my phpMyAdmin page I get this error:

```
(HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES).
```

NOTE: I haven’t changed nothing i just turn the server off and then on again.
After searching the web and trying diferent things, I found that deleting `mysql-bin.index` fixes the problem, but why? I think I shouldn't do that it is not supposed that the user has to delete that every time on turns the server off.

Comment: Does this really happen all the time? What OS are you on? If you stop MAMP  and then  start  it again, what happens? It should be fine.

Comment: @JakeGould Yes it happens all the time, im using windows 10. If i stop and then start it again after the first time, it just dont connect SQL server anymore until i delete the file mentioned above. i found it out when i unistalled MAMP and saw that there were folders that werent deleted by the uninstaller, and if i installed mamp again without removing that folders(specifically that file) it would not work either.